# Kernel Panic - Not Syncing: Fatal exception

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, kernel-panic

Server (HP Proliant D320e G8 v2) froze at this screen during boot today (running CentOS 6.5):

[image: Kernel panic capture.]

I was able to get the server to boot after a 'press and hold'.

I've been having many problems with the server lately - mainly related to the iLO and being unable to install CentOS 7. Could someone please help me decode this screen? Does it suggest there could be a serious problem? Or does this just happen sometimes? It is possible that the OS wasn't 'shutdown' properly before the failed boot.

Comment: Unfortunately the stack trace isn't telling much. I suggest you start with a full memory check (probably available in the HP BIOS diagnostics option).

Comment: The `Tainted: P` part means there is a proprietary module in the kernel. As far as I know official policy is that you ask the vendor of the proprietary module to debug the problem.

Comment: If the stack indicates any interaction with the proprietary driver, probably. However, that will be the longest investigation route most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Silly question, but have you [checked the firmware](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/6195/im-tired-of-answering-questions-with-upgrade-the-firmware-or-run-updates) on your machine and its components?

I ask because the [changelogs for the DL320e Gen8 firmware](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=5249567&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_1e167270c3e74c24a10ef0f3ab%257CswEnvOID%253D4103%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D5%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) include valuable nuggets like:

> Resolved a processor issue where certain instructions and conditions
>   could result in an application-level error, blue screen, kernel panic,
>   or other unpredictable system behavior. This issue affects platforms
>   utilizing Intel Xeon E3-series processors.

There are a couple of things I'd recommend here.

- Set up and configure the Intelligent Provisioning menu (`F10`). You may actually want to update it first via CD or ILO. See the [download from HP's support site](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/management/ilo/index.aspx#tab=TAB5).
- Just download the [full HP Service Pack for ProLiant bootable firmware DVD](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx) and let it run unattended.

This will bring your system fully up-to-date to a known-good firmware revision. It may also help with your EL7 efforts, as it *is* technically supported on this hardware platform.